# How to implement permutations with size limit?

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

I have a simple permutation code that only allows permutation of the entire input. Does anyone know a way to permutate with a size limit? For e.g. 4P2 of 1234 will give (12, 23, 34, 14, 24, 13 etc...), instead of 4P4.

The code for reference

```
static ArrayList<int[]> permutations(int[] a) {
    ArrayList<int[]> temp = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    permutation(a, 0, temp);
    return temp;
}

public static void permutation(int[] arr, int pos, ArrayList<int[]> list){
    if(arr.length - pos == 1)
        list.add(arr.clone());
    else
        for(int i = pos; i < arr.length; i++){
            swap(arr, pos, i);
            permutation(arr, pos+1, list);
            swap(arr, pos, i);
        }
}

public static void swap(int[] arr, int pos1, int pos2){
    int h = arr[pos1];
    arr[pos1] = arr[pos2];
    arr[pos2] = h;
}
```

Comment: If order does not matter then it is not `nPr`, it is not a permutation calculation, rather it is a combination calculation `nCr` or *n choose r*.

Comment: Hi, sorry I edited to order does matter. Do you know how to limit the size on the permutation?